# Migrating to unique_ptr from a dynamic array and failing to convert to std::span

Tags: c++, vector, unique-ptr, c++20

I'm trying to encrypt and decrypt a file, basically exercising `std::span` and `std::unique_ptr`. The issues are commented in the code.

1. 2nd parameter of `rc4` is `std::span` but my parameters are `vector<uint8_t>` for the encryption and `unique_ptr<uint8_t>` for the decryption, which I'm unable to convert to.
2. `*output++ = elem ^ s[(s[i] + s[j]) % 256];` cannot be done with unique_ptr.

```cpp
const auto log_data = read_log_file(log_path);
const auto log_size = static_cast<std::size_t>(std::filesystem::file_size(log_path));

// Generate a random key
std::uint8_t key[32];
generate_random_key(key);

// Encrypt
const auto result = std::make_unique<std::uint8_t>(log_size);

rc4_context context{};
rc4(&context, log_data, key, std::move(result)); // TODO: log_data: Cannot convert lvalue of type const std::vector<uint8_t> to parameter type const std::span<uint8_t>

// Decrypt
const auto result2 = std::make_unique<std::uint8_t>(log_size);
rc4(&context, std::move(result), key, std::move(result2)); // TODO: Again the second parameter cannot be casted from unique_ptr<unsigned char> to span<uint8_t>
```

```cpp
std::vector<std::uint8_t> read_log_file(const std::wstring& path)
{
    std::ifstream ifs(path, std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);

    if (!ifs)
        throw std::runtime_error("Could not load file.");

    const auto end = ifs.tellg();
    ifs.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

    const auto size = static_cast<std::size_t>(end - ifs.tellg());

    if (size == 0)
        return {};

    std::vector<std::uint8_t> buffer(size);

    if (!ifs.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(buffer.data()), buffer.size()))
        throw std::runtime_error("Could not read file.");

    return buffer;
}

int rc4(rc4_context* context, const std::span<std::uint8_t>& data, const std::span<std::uint8_t>& key, const std::unique_ptr<std::uint8_t>& output)
{
    // INITIALIZATION
    std::uint32_t i, j;

    // Check parameters
    if (!context || !key.empty())
        return ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER;

    // Clear context
    context->i = 0;
    context->j = 0;

    // Initialize the S array with identity permutation
    for (i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        context->s[i] = static_cast<std::uint8_t>(i);
    }

    // S is then processed for 256 iterations
    for (i = 0, j = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        // Randomize the permutations using the supplied key
        j = (j + context->s[i] + key[i % key.size()]) % 256;

        // Swap the values of S[i] and S[j]
        const auto temp = context->s[i];
        context->s[i] = context->s[j];
        context->s[j] = temp;
    }

    // MAIN LOGIC PART
    // Restore context
    i = context->i;
    j = context->j;
    auto* s = context->s;
    
    // Encryption loop
    for (auto elem : data)
    {
        // Adjust indices
        i = (i + 1) % 256;
        j = (j + s[i]) % 256;

        // Swap the values of S[i] and S[j]
        std::swap(s[i], s[j]);

        // Valid output?
        if (output)
        {
            // XOR the input data with the RC4 stream
            *output++ = elem ^ s[(s[i] + s[j]) % 256]; // TODO: error happens here, because of *output++
        }
    }

    // Save context
    context->i = i;
    context->j = j;

    return NO_ERROR;
}
```

Comment: Whenever you think "dynamic array" you next thought should almost always be `std::vector`.

Comment: In `const auto result = std::make_unique<std::uint8_t>(log_size);` you allocate _one_ `uint8_t` that you initialize with the value `log_size`. Is that what you really want?

Comment: Also [the `std::span` constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span/span) have a couple of overloads that can used to create a span from a vector (using iterators).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude about that, I've tried `std::span log(log_data);` and then `rc4(&context, log, key, std::move(result));`, `log` returns `Cannot convert lvalue of type std::span<const unsigned char, 4294967295> to parameter type const std::span<uint8_t>`

Comment: 4294967295 looks like the `signed` 32 bit value -1  using `unsigned` eyes.

Comment: @TedLyngmo That's probably the value of [`std::dynamic_extent`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span/dynamic_extent) which is a special constant for spans without a compile-time size.

Comment: @nop You might have to explicitly define the `std::dynamic_extent` template argument for the span in your function declaration.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, it's okay to change the function signature as long as it works for both cases: encryption and decryption

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using `std::vector<uint8_t>` for `result` too, but here's how you can fix the code you've got. I've made it minimal in the answer to focus on the issues.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <span>
#include <vector>

// rc4's span should be over const uint8_t's:
void rc4(const std::span<const std::uint8_t>& data) {
    std::cout << data.size() << '\n';
}

int main() {
    size_t log_size = 100;

    const std::vector<uint8_t> log_data{1, 2, 3};   // ... since this is const
    rc4(log_data);

    // you should allocate an array, not a single uint8_t here:
    const auto result = std::make_unique<std::uint8_t[]>(log_size);

    // and you can create the span like this in your argument list:
    rc4( {result.get(), log_size} );
}
```

Output:

```
3
100
```

---

An alternative using `vector`s for both input and output:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

int rc4(const std::vector<std::uint8_t>& data,
        std::vector<std::uint8_t>& output)
{
    output.clear();
    output.reserve(data.size());

    for(auto byte : data) {
        output.push_back(0xFF - byte);              // a simple algoritm
    }

    return 0; // NO_ERROR;
}

int main() {  
    const std::vector<uint8_t> log_data{'A', 'B', 'C'};
    std::vector<std::uint8_t> result;

    rc4(log_data, result);                          // encrypt

    for(auto byte : result) {
        std::cout << std::hex << (int)byte << '\n'; // probably be, bd, bc
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    std::vector<std::uint8_t> result2;
    rc4(result, result2);                           // decrypt

    for(auto byte : result2) {
        std::cout << byte;                          // prints ABC
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I actually made the result `vector`, because it just looks better. `const std::vector<std::uint8_t> result(log_size);`. One issue left tho. `if (output)
        {
            // XOR the input data with the RC4 stream
            *output++ = elem ^ s[(s[i] + s[j]) % 256];
        }`  This doesn't work with vector/unique_ptr. The incrementing is not suitable with them

Comment: @nop `const std::unique_ptr<std::uint8_t>& output` is also a pointer to a single `uint8_t`. You'd have to make that an array too (or a `vector<uint8_t>`)  You can't do `output++` on any of them though. Use the member `operator[]` or, if you use a `vector<uint8_t>`, its `begin()` iterator and step that forward.

Comment: I used a vector. This is the function `https://pastebin.com/B4QnknER`. I made it like `if (output.empty())
        {
            // XOR the input data with the RC4 stream
            output[x] = data[x] ^ s[(s[i] + s[j]) % 256];
        }`. Or is .begin() better?

Comment: @nop I'd probably start with an empty output vector and just `push_back` the new values into it. I made an [example](https://godbolt.org/z/sadzPxsWe) using your original `unique_ptr`'s but I guess that's old news now? :-)

Comment: @nop I added an alternative for using vectors too.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/sNBFbJd3 `result` and `result2` seem to be empty for me :/

Comment: @nop Remove `if (output.empty())` before the `push_back` - it prevents adding more than one `uint8_t` into `output`

Comment: Works fine! Thank you very much! :)